# Is marriage taken place?

Tags: nikah

Let's say both families of man and woman wished to unite them through marriage, but woman dont want to marry the man as she had previous relation (her family did not disclose to others); being forced by woman's parents she agreed to marry the man after 3/4 months, but woman's parents asked both man and woman to sign the marriage paper and no need to say (i agree/ verbal confirmation in front of imam ), after 3/4 months they will complete the marriage (including verbal agreement), then imam will listen to both man's and woman's verbal agreement and then complete the marriage. By the way man also signed the paper including 2 witness and mohor info into paper. Imam didn't make any verbal talking related to marriage including asking either they were agreed to marry one another or not. And write down on wedding paper (no marriage taken place) in Imam's signing position.

After 3 months still woman didn't want to marry. so now what is their relation? is their marriage complete ? if they want to separate what they need to do?

Comment: Assuming the marriage has taken place as i really couldn't follow you, a forced marriage could be a reason for the woman to go to court to make  invalidate it, as this is her right! See my answer here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28283/what-do-i-do-about-my-marriage?rq=1

Comment: did she also sign paper in front of 2 witnesses? but even if did, i think witnesses should be same persons for agreements of both sides, including agreement of wali.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear so I would just state some general things. Firstly, a woman may not be married without her permission. And even if she had been forcefully married, she has the option to opt out of the marriage due to the hadith:

> Narrated Abdullah ibn Abbas: "A virgin came to the Prophet
>   (peace be upon him) and mentioned that her father had married her
>   against her will, so the Prophet (peace be upon him) allowed her to
>   exercise her choice.  (Translation of Sunan Abu-Dawud, Marriage (Kitab
>   Al-Nikah), Book 11, Number 2091)"

With regards to the marriage itself, it is valid if:

1. It is with the permission of her father/guardian
2. The dowry has been paid
3. There are at least 2 witnesses
4. Her permission has been sought

If these conditions have been met, then the marriage is valid. However, like I said before, she still has the option to opt out of the marriage if it has been forced on her.